# twisted: processing incoming events in synchronous code

Tags: python, event-handling, twisted

Suppose there's a synchronous function in a twisted-powered Python program that takes a long time to execute, doing that in a lot of reasonable-sized pieces of work.  If the function could return deferreds, this would be a no-brainer, however the function happens to be deep inside some synchronous code, so that yielding deferreds to continue is impossible.

Is there a way to let twisted handle outstanding events without leaving that function? I.e. what I want to do is something along the lines of

```py
def my_func():
    results = []
    for item in a_lot_of_items():
        results.append(do_computation(item))
        reactor.process_outstanding_events()
    return results
```

Of course, this imposes reentrancy requirements on the code, but still, there's [QCoreApplication.processEvents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) for that in Qt, is there anything in twisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution taken by some event-loop-based systems (essentially the solution you're referencing via Qt's `QCoreApplication.processEvents` API) is to make the main loop re-entrant.  In Twisted terms, this would mean something like (**not** working code):

```
def my_expensive_task_that_cannot_be_asynchronous():
    @inlineCallbacks
    def do_work(units):
        for unit in units:
            yield do_one_work_asynchronously(unit)
    work = do_work(some_work_units())
    work.addBoth(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()

def main():
    # Whatever your setup is...
    # Then, hypothetical event source triggering your
    # expensive function:
    reactor.callLater(
        30,
        my_expensive_task_that_cannot_be_asynchronous,
    )
    reactor.run()
```

Notice how there are *two* `reactor.run` calls in this program.  If Twisted had a re-entrant event loop, this second call would start spinning the reactor again and not return until a matching `reactor.stop` call is encountered.  The reactor would process all events it knows about, not just the ones generated by `do_work`, and so you would have the behavior you desire.

This requires a re-entrant event loop because `my_expensive_task_...` is already being called by the reactor loop.  The reactor loop is on the call stack.  Then, `reactor.run` is called and the reactor loop is now on the call stack *again*.  So the usual issues apply: the event loop cannot have left over state in its frame (otherwise it may be invalid by the time the nested call is complete), it cannot leave its instance state inconsistent during any calls out to other code, etc.

Twisted does not have a re-entrant event loop.  This is a feature that has been considered and, at least in the past, explicitly rejected.  Supporting this features brings a huge amount of additional complexity (described above) to the implementation *and* the application.  If the event loop is re-entrant then it becomes very difficult to avoid requiring all application code to be re-entrant safe as well.  This negates one of the major benefits of the cooperative multitasking approach Twisted takes to concurrency (that you are guaranteed your functions will not be re-entered).

So, when using Twisted, this solution is out.

I'm not aware of another solution which would allow you to continue to run this code in the reactor thread.  You mentioned that the code in question is nested deeply within some other synchronous code.  The other options that come to mind are:

- make the synchronous code capable of dealing with asynchronous things
- factor the expensive parts out and compute them first, then pass the result in to the rest of the code
- run *all* of that code, not just the computationally expensive part, in another thread

Answer (score 0):

You could use deferToThread.

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/core/howto/threading.html

That method runs your calculation in a separate thread and returns a deferred that is called back when the calculation is actually finished.

Comment: That would help, if I could return the result of `my_func` as deferred, but like I said, it is buried deeply in synchronous code, and to return a deferred I have to rewrite it all to bubble the deferred up all the way to the event loop.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect that single iteration time is OK, rather that the whole iteration time is too long.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
for item in items:
    reactor.callLater(0, heavy_func, item)
```

reactor.callLater should bring you back into the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is if `do_heavy_computation()` is  code that blocks then execution won't go to the next function. In this case use `deferToThread` or `blockingCallFromThread` for heavy calculations. Also if you don't care for the results of the calculation then you can use `callInThread`. Take a look at [documentation on threads](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html)

Comment: OK, i see how i might have confused people with the "heavy" part. processing of one item is fine, the delay really starts to kick in when there's a lot of them.

Let me edit the question a bit.